# Performance impact when querying without partition key on a partitioned table

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, amazon-rds, benchmarking, partitioning

Assuming I partition a table of large size (say 6TB) by month. We are serving very high traffic of around 300 RPS.

Sample schema

```
Create table mydata(
    id bigint not null,
    date_created not null,
    uuid_val not null,
    Primary key (id,date_created),
    key uuid_idx uuid_val
    ) Partition by range(to_days(date_created) ...
```

What will be the performance impact if I query on this table without date_created in the where clause.
It will not give a better performance for sure as it cannot do partition pruning but what will the impact be if I query it based on index uuid_val as compared to a non-partitioned table with same schema?

I tried benchmarking it with 6GB data and querying(500,000 times) by index and not partition key the overhead to search in multiple partitions seemed very less (0.1ms) as compared to running the same query on the non-partitioned table. But why is the overhead so less.
Also can I expect such numbers with 6TB data too when serving high traffic?
Can I query partitioned table without partition key as I might not have in the flow.

My MySQL version is 8. Engine = InnoDB

Comment: Are you sure that `id INT` did not overflow??  2 billion rows in 6TB smells like a problem.

Comment: Will you be deleting "old" rows, and that is the reason for partitioning?  If no, then what is the reason?  How many partitions does the table have?

Comment: Yes, i will be deleting the rows. Table will have 12 partitions.

Sorry, int will be of type bigint. Changing it

Comment: If that is monthly purging, I recommend 14 partitions.  See [_Partition_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)

Comment: "500,000 times" -- same value?  Or random values?  I ask because of caching considerations.

Comment: What datatype is `uuid_val`?  Please answer that and other possible questions by providing the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE mydata`.

Answer (score 0):

> what will the impact be if I query it based on index uuid_val as compared to a non-partitioned table with same schema?

In MySQL, all indexes are local to a partition.

Since partition pruning is impossible if you don't provide the paritioning key value as a part of the query, the engine will have to query all your table's partitions.

If you have (for example) three partitions, that's three times as much work.

Within each partition, the query plan will be exactly the same (i.e. index seek on `uuid_val`.

> Can I query partitioned table without partition key as I might not have in the flow.

Yes, you can, with the above limitation.

Comment: I did testing with 6GB data and 500,000 queries but average difference was 0.1 ms.
How much is the performance impact when data is TBs.
Even when it is searching multiple partitions, the size of the index in each partition will be less. What will be the overhead. Should not be thrice the time taken by a non-partitioned table

Comment: @HarshitaMishra: "average difference was 0.1 ms" — difference between what and what? "What will be the overhead" — overhead over what?

Comment: @HarshitaMishra: index seek time is O(log n), where n is the number of records, and it grows in discrete steps, as your B-tree acquires more levels. Partitions grow linearly. If you have a single 1tb partition, that's ~12 seeks. If you have 1000 1gb partitions, that's ~1000*9 = ~900 seeks. Depending on your query, it will do row lookups as well, but they scale in exact same way.